# React Starter Kit Error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I created a new React TypeScript app using the starter kit - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#typescript-react-starter

After following the instructions, I came across the following error while trying to serve the app (i.e. after I ran `npm run start`)

```
Failed to compile.
C:\*****\node_modules\@types\react-dom\index.d.ts (16,43): error TS2305: Module '"C:/****/node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no exported member 'ReactPortal'.
```

I am new to React (and vaguely familiar with Node and NPM), and I do not understand the `no exported member` aspect?

Help.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. In the initial package.json file that is used to build the node modules, under the `"devDependencies"` key, the `"@types/react": <version>` was different than the version under the `"dependencies"` key. Ensure that these versions are consistent.

For me, the version under `"dependencies"` was `"^16.0.0"`, so I changed the version under `"devDependencies"` to `"^16.0.0"`.